# Timestamps with nanoseconds on xaxis

Tags: datetime, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, axis-labels

I have a conversion of timestamps to `DateTime` objects as below:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = {'Timestamp':['20160208_095900.51','20160208_095901.51','20160208_095902.51','20160208_095903.51',
                 '20160208_095904.51','20160208_095905.51','20160208_095906.51','20160208_095907.51',
                 '20160208_095908.51','20160208_095909.51'],
      'Data' : [2300,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000,3100,3200,3300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(s1)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format = '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.%f')

print df

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(df.Date, df.Data)
```

As can be seen from this example, the plotting is done using the whole time object, including the information down to nanosecond level. This makes the xlables hard to read. 
Is there a way to 'clean' the x lables with an option in the plotting or already in the conversion? 
I would like the timestamp to appear in the format **HH:MM:SS**.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) to specify the date format:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

s1 = {'Timestamp':['20160208_095900.51','20160208_095901.51','20160208_095902.51','20160208_095903.51',
                 '20160208_095904.51','20160208_095905.51','20160208_095906.51','20160208_095907.51',
                 '20160208_095908.51','20160208_095909.51'],
      'Data' : [2300,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000,3100,3200,3300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(s1)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format = '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.%f')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
# automatically rotates the tick labels
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Data'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all those quick suggestions. Finally, I used this method as it best fits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is create new column with custom format by [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Date1'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
print (df)
   Data           Timestamp                    Date     Date1
0  2300  20160208_095900.51 2016-02-08 09:59:00.510  09:59:00
1  2500  20160208_095901.51 2016-02-08 09:59:01.510  09:59:01
2  2600  20160208_095902.51 2016-02-08 09:59:02.510  09:59:02
3  2700  20160208_095903.51 2016-02-08 09:59:03.510  09:59:03
4  2800  20160208_095904.51 2016-02-08 09:59:04.510  09:59:04
5  2900  20160208_095905.51 2016-02-08 09:59:05.510  09:59:05
6  3000  20160208_095906.51 2016-02-08 09:59:06.510  09:59:06
7  3100  20160208_095907.51 2016-02-08 09:59:07.510  09:59:07
8  3200  20160208_095908.51 2016-02-08 09:59:08.510  09:59:08
9  3300  20160208_095909.51 2016-02-08 09:59:09.510  09:59:09

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
df.plot(x='Date1', y='Data', rot=40)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

If index is not important, you can set new index by custom `datetime` and then use [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
df.index = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
print (df)
          Data           Timestamp                    Date
Date                                                      
09:59:00  2300  20160208_095900.51 2016-02-08 09:59:00.510
09:59:01  2500  20160208_095901.51 2016-02-08 09:59:01.510
09:59:02  2600  20160208_095902.51 2016-02-08 09:59:02.510
09:59:03  2700  20160208_095903.51 2016-02-08 09:59:03.510
09:59:04  2800  20160208_095904.51 2016-02-08 09:59:04.510
09:59:05  2900  20160208_095905.51 2016-02-08 09:59:05.510
09:59:06  3000  20160208_095906.51 2016-02-08 09:59:06.510
09:59:07  3100  20160208_095907.51 2016-02-08 09:59:07.510
09:59:08  3200  20160208_095908.51 2016-02-08 09:59:08.510
09:59:09  3300  20160208_095909.51 2016-02-08 09:59:09.510

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
df.Data.plot(rot=40)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this lazy approach?

```
In [11]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

In [12]: df.set_index(df.Date.dt.time).plot(ax=ax, rot=40)
Out[12]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x99de438>
```

[image]